# How to work with background threads in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a heavy duty calculatuion that I need to do, and due to gateway timeout I want to run the calculation in background thread. 
I used python threading but it is not working.

```py
import time
import threading
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

def heavy_func():
    time.sleep(20)
    print('Hi!')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_method():
    threading.Thread(target=heavy_func()).start()
    return 'hello!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

it works in synchronous way instead of asynchronous which I want

Answer (score 4):

Use thread.daemon as following.

```
import time
import threading
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

def heavy_func():
    time.sleep(20)
    print('Hi!')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_method(): 
    thread = threading.Thread(target=heavy_func)
    thread.daemon = True         # Daemonize 
    thread.start()
    return "work is in progress"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways you can start an async thread in Flask. I wrote a small article on that https://smirnov-am.github.io/background-jobs-with-flask/

Comment: cant install uWSGI in windows

Comment: so I can't check it in my local PC

Comment: shouldn't we use app.app_context().push() in tasks.py?